# Convert text file to source code file [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10

I would like to change a plain text file `code.txt` into a c++ source code file `code.cpp`. I would think this would amount to only a simple renaming of the file, but on Windows 10 I can't see how to do this. I seem to not be able to change the file extension.

Comment: Try clicking on the View tab in the ribbon menu, then show extensions for known file types.  Otherwise, open notepad, paste your code, then save as, select All Files, and enter the ,cpp extension yourself and save,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every programming language (with a few exceptions) are all text files.

You should just select the text file in File Explorer, right click, select rename, and enter in `code.cpp`.  CPP is the common C++ extension for C++ programs.

If you do not see extension, click the `View` menu item in the menu bar in File Explorer, and uncheck `Hide file extensions`.  This will allow you to rename the file and extension.

Comment: Windows by default hides the extensions.  Renaming it to `code.cpp` would result in `code.cpp.txt` where the `.txt` is hidden in Windows.

Comment: @Peter irrelevant.  by adding the .CPP, windows will rename .txt to .cpp

Comment: @that is assuming he has hide file extensions turned on

Comment: @Keltari Not in Explorer while renaming with file extensions hidden. At least it never did for me.